# How to make a component that renders 4 different sliders?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

How to make reusable components like a slider? I don't like that
most of it is repeated, but if everything is combined, it will not be clear at all, what does each slider do?

```
function Slider({
  title,
  titleStyle,
  children,
  type,
  paginationClass,
  isGrid,
  className,
}) {
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ maxWidth: 991 });

  const linksModules = isGrid ? [Grid, FreeMode] : [FreeMode];

  // banners
  if (type === "banners") {
    return (
      <div className="sliderBanners">
        {title && <h6 className={`title ${titleStyle}`}>{title}</h6>}
        {!isMobile && (
          <div className="carousel-recommendation-buttons">
            <button type="button" className="carousel-recommendation-prev">
              <PrevCarouselRec />
            </button>
            <button type="button" className="carousel-recommendation-next">
              <NextCarouselRec />
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
        <Swiper
          slidesPerView={isMobile ? "auto" : 4}
          freeMode
          preventClicks={false}
          preventClicksPropagation={false}
          pagination={{
            el: `.${paginationClass}`,
          }}
          modules={[Navigation, Pagination, FreeMode]}
          className="carouselItemsSlider"
          navigation={
            !isMobile && {
              nextEl: `.carousel-recommendation-next`,
              prevEl: `.carousel-recommendation-prev`,
            }
          }
          breakpoints={{
            320: {
              spaceBetween: 11,
            },
            480: {
              spaceBetween: 13,
            },
            991: {
              slidesPerView: 4,
              spaceBetween: 16,
            },
          }}
        >
          {children}
        </Swiper>
        <div
          className={`carousel-pagination itemsPagination ${paginationClass}`}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  // links
  if (type === "links") {
    return (
      <>
        {title && <h4 className={titleStyle}>{title}</h4>}
        <Swiper
          slidesPerView="auto"
          modules={linksModules}
          className={className}
          freeMode
          grid={
            isGrid && {
              rows: 2,
              fill: "row",
            }
          }
          breakpoints={{
            320: {
              spaceBetween: 7,
            },
            480: {
              spaceBetween: 14,
            },
            768: {
              spaceBetween: 20,
            },
          }}
        >
          {children}
        </Swiper>
      </>
    );
  }

  // main
  if (type === "main") {
    return (
      <div className="sliderMain">
        {title && <h6 className={`title ${titleStyle}`}>{title}</h6>}
        <button className="carousel-prev" type="button">
          <PrevCarousel />
        </button>
        <button className="carousel-next" type="button">
          <NextCarousel />
        </button>
        <Swiper
          slidesPerView={1}
          autoplay={{
            delay: 400000,
          }}
          pagination={{
            el: `.mainPagination`,
          }}
          observer
          observeParents
          modules={[Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination]}
          className="mainSlider"
          spaceBetween={27}
          loop
          navigation={{
            nextEl: `.carousel-next`,
            prevEl: `.carousel-prev`,
          }}
        >
          {children}
        </Swiper>
        <div className="carousel-pagination mainPagination" />
      </div>
    );
  }

  // items
  return (
    <div className="sliderContainer">
      {title && <h6 className={`title ${titleStyle}`}>{title}</h6>}
      {!isMobile && (
        <div className="carousel-recommendation-buttons">
          <button type="button" className="carousel-recommendation-prev">
            <PrevCarouselRec />
          </button>
          <button type="button" className="carousel-recommendation-next">
            <NextCarouselRec />
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
      <Swiper
        slidesPerView={4}
        autoplay={{
          delay: 400000,
          disableOnInteraction: true,
        }}
        pagination={{
          el: `.${paginationClass}`,
        }}
        observer
        observeParents
        modules={[Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination]}
        className="carouselItemsSlider"
        spaceBetween={27}
        loop
        navigation={{
          nextEl: `.carousel-recommendation-next`,
          prevEl: `.carousel-recommendation-prev`,
        }}
        breakpoints={{
          320: {
            slidesPerGroup: 2,
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 12,
          },
          600: {
            slidesPerGroup: 3,
            slidesPerView: 3,
          },
          1040: {
            slidesPerGroup: 4,
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 25,
          },
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </Swiper>
      <div
        className={`carousel-pagination itemsPagination ${paginationClass}`}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to write ternary expressions, so it was not clear what returned to this opinion, and now I don’t know how to do it better. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one approach where you can continue to add more sliders wihout breaking existing ones

The second approach involves a trade off with code repetation and maintainability, which I can explain if needed.

first approach, less repeating code
function Slider({
title,
titleStyle,
children,
type,
paginationClass,
isGrid,
className,
}) {
const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ maxWidth: 991 });

```
  const linksModules = isGrid ? [Grid, FreeMode] : [FreeMode];

  // get properties for each type
  const {
      navigationProps,
      containerClass
  } = useMemo(() => {

     // this function can ideally be moved outside
     if (type === "banners") {

        return {
          navigationProps={
             !isMobile && {
             nextEl: `.carousel-recommendation-next`,
             prevEl: `.carousel-recommendation-prev`,
          }
         },
        containerClass: {`carousel-pagination itemsPagination ${paginationClass}`
       }

     } else {
       return {
          // default properties
       }
     }

  }, [type]

 const  mobileProps = !isMobile && (
      <div className="carousel-recommendation-buttons">
        <button type="button" className="carousel-recommendation-prev">
          <PrevCarouselRec />
        </button>
        <button type="button" className="carousel-recommendation-next">
          <NextCarouselRec />
        </button>
      </div>
    )

  // set properties accordingly
  return (
    <div className="sliderBanners">
      {title && <h6 className={`title ${titleStyle}`}>{title}</h6>}
      {mobileProps}
      <Swiper
        slidesPerView={isMobile ? "auto" : 4}
        freeMode
        preventClicks={false}
        preventClicksPropagation={false}
        pagination={{
          el: `.${paginationClass}`,
        }}
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination, FreeMode]}
        className="carouselItemsSlider"
        navigation={navigationProps}
        breakpoints={{
          320: {
           spaceBetween: 11,
         },
          480: {
            spaceBetween: 13,
          },
          991: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 16,
          },
         }}
        >
          {children}
        </Swiper>
        <div className={containerClass} />
     </div>
    );
   }
  )


}
```

even you need even more seperation and dont mind repeating some markup, i.e trading repeating code for better maintainability, you can create seperate components and pick them up dynamically based on type, I can explain that if you like

Hope this helps you in some way